# Fragment shader does not show any colour when compiled with vs2013

Tags: opengl, ffmpeg, glsl, rgb, yuv

When compiled with vs2010, the fragment shader works, but when I compiled and run in vs 2013, it's grey.

My fragment shader converts the yuv texture into rgb

Below is my fragment code

```
    const char *FProgram =
    "uniform sampler2D Ytex;\n"
    "uniform sampler2D Utex;\n"
    "uniform sampler2D Vtex;\n"
    "void main(void) {\n"
    "  vec4 c = vec4((texture2D(Ytex, gl_TexCoord[0]).r - 16./255.) * 1.164);\n"
    "  vec4 U = vec4(texture2D(Utex, gl_TexCoord[0]).r - 128./255.);\n"
    "  vec4 V = vec4(texture2D(Vtex, gl_TexCoord[0]).r - 128./255.);\n"
    "  c += V * vec4(1.596, -0.813, 0, 0);\n"
    "  c += U * vec4(0, -0.392, 2.017, 0);\n"
    "  c.a = 1.0;\n"
    "  gl_FragColor = c;\n"
    "}\n";





glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

PHandle = glCreateProgram();
FSHandle = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);



glShaderSource(FSHandle, 1, &FProgram, NULL);
glCompileShader(FSHandle);

glAttachShader(PHandle, FSHandle);
glLinkProgram(PHandle);


glUseProgram(PHandle);
glDeleteProgram(PHandle);
glDeleteProgram(FSHandle);
```

This is my texture code, I receive linesize and yuv frame data from ffmpeg and make into texture. Everything works fine in VS 2010 computer, but when compiled and run in vs2013 computer, it is grey (black n white), no colour

```
    /* Select texture unit 1 as the active unit and bind the U texture. */
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, linesize1);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
i = glGetUniformLocation(PHandle, "Utex");
glUniform1i(i, 1);  /* Bind Utex to texture unit 1 */
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, width / 2, height / 2, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, frame1);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);


/* Select texture unit 2 as the active unit and bind the V texture. */
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, linesize2);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
i = glGetUniformLocation(PHandle, "Vtex");
glUniform1i(i, 2);  /* Bind Vtext to texture unit 2 */
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, width / 2, height / 2, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, frame2);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);


/* Select texture unit 0 as the active unit and bind the Y texture. */



glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, linesize0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
i = glGetUniformLocation(PHandle, "Ytex");
glUniform1i(i, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, width, height, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, frame0);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);



glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

/* Draw image (again and again). */

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2i(0, 0);
glVertex2i(-w / 2, h / 2);
glTexCoord2i(1, 0);
glVertex2i(w / 2, h / 2);
glTexCoord2i(1, 1);
glVertex2i(w / 2, -h / 2);
glTexCoord2i(0, 1);
glVertex2i(-w / 2, -h / 2);
glEnd();
```

Comment: Is it even legal to initialize a vec4 with a single scalar? Any reason you're not just initializing all members of the vec4?

Comment: Tried initializing everything but did not work.

But I solved it by referring to this: http://www.fourcc.org/source/YUV420P-OpenGL-GLSLang.c

Hope it helps.